# How to intercept every not asset calls to constantly render the index.html file

Tags: loopbackjs

I have built an SPA Application, i need to deploy it on a loopback server, and i never used it, so i am lost with all of these json files you can configure to intercept the calls.

I simply need to intercept every calls (expect static files) and to return my index.html file for every cases.

Technically, it is just a middleware that is invocked after the "serve-static" middleware and say "ok if you are here, you are not an asset, render the index.html file".

My / path already return the index.html, how am i supposed to implement that rule properly with loopback?

I guess it is going to happens on the `middleware.json` file, so mine currently looks like this:

```json
{
  "initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
  },
  "initial": {
    "compression": {},
    "cors": {
      "params": {
        "origin": true,
        "credentials": true,
        "maxAge": 86400
      }
    }
  },
  "session": {
  },
  "auth": {
  },
  "parse": {
  },
  "routes": {
    "loopback#rest": {
      "paths": ["${restApiRoot}"]
    }
  },
  "files": {
    "serve-static": {
      "params": "$!../client"
    }
  },
  "final": {
    "loopback#urlNotFound": {}
  },
  "final:after": {
    "loopback#errorHandler": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can a middleware which will check if nodejs has already served a request, if not redirect to `/`.

```
//in middleware.json  
"final:before": {
    "./middleware/redirect.js": {},
}

//in server/middleware/redirect.js
module.exports = function() {

    return function redirect(request, response, next) {
        if (!response.headersSent) {
            response.redirect('/');
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
};
```